# Is multi choice django admin filters possible..?

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose if there is a model named 'Cities' and at admin side there is a filter 'city_name' to filter model based on city names.
By default django only allows to choose one city name from the django admin filter.
But I need to choose multipile city names in django admin filter.How can i do that.??

Answer (score 6):

You can use a slightly modified version of built in [AllValuesFieldListFilter](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/filters.py#L378):

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.utils import reverse_field_path
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class MultiSelectFieldListFilter(admin.FieldListFilter):
    def __init__(self, field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path):
        self.lookup_kwarg = field_path + '__in'
        self.lookup_kwarg_isnull = field_path + '__isnull'

        super().__init__(field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path)

        self.lookup_val = self.used_parameters.get(self.lookup_kwarg, [])
        if len(self.lookup_val) == 1 and self.lookup_val[0] == '':
            self.lookup_val = []
        self.lookup_val_isnull = self.used_parameters.get(self.lookup_kwarg_isnull)

        self.empty_value_display = model_admin.get_empty_value_display()
        parent_model, reverse_path = reverse_field_path(model, field_path)
        # Obey parent ModelAdmin queryset when deciding which options to show
        if model == parent_model:
            queryset = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
        else:
            queryset = parent_model._default_manager.all()
        self.lookup_choices = queryset.distinct().order_by(field.name).values_list(field.name, flat=True)

    def expected_parameters(self):
        return [self.lookup_kwarg, self.lookup_kwarg_isnull]

    def choices(self, changelist):
        yield {
            'selected': not self.lookup_val and self.lookup_val_isnull is None,
            'query_string': changelist.get_query_string(remove=[self.lookup_kwarg, self.lookup_kwarg_isnull]),
            'display': _('All'),
        }
        include_none = False
        for val in self.lookup_choices:
            if val is None:
                include_none = True
                continue
            val = str(val)

            if val in self.lookup_val:
                values = [v for v in self.lookup_val if v != val]
            else:
                values = self.lookup_val + [ val ]

            if values:
                yield {
                    'selected': val in self.lookup_val,
                    'query_string': changelist.get_query_string({self.lookup_kwarg: ','.join(values)}, [self.lookup_kwarg_isnull]),
                    'display': val,
                }
            else:
                yield {
                    'selected': val in self.lookup_val,
                    'query_string': changelist.get_query_string(remove=[self.lookup_kwarg]),
                    'display': val,
                }

        if include_none:
            yield {
                'selected': bool(self.lookup_val_isnull),
                'query_string': changelist.get_query_string({self.lookup_kwarg_isnull: 'True'}, [self.lookup_kwarg]),
                'display': self.empty_value_display,
            }
```

Escaping commas in values should be implemented too, but I didn't need it.

(Tested with Django 2.2.5)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this new tool [django-admin-multiple-choice-list-filter](https://github.com/ctxis/django-admin-multiple-choice-list-filter).

Comment: Currently this repository seems [unmaintained](https://github.com/ctxis/django-admin-multiple-choice-list-filter/issues/4).

Answer (score 4):

For those who would rather use external libraries, these seem to be maintained (releases within the last 6 months) at the time of writing:

[django-more-admin-filters](https://github.com/thomst/django-more-admin-filters): adds several filter classes incl. multi select and dropdown filters

[django-advanced-filters](https://github.com/modlinltd/django-advanced-filters): adds an advanced filter mixin that can display a modal to build queries with several conditions combined by and/or

Not related to the question but also a nice find:

[django-admin-autocomplete-list-filter](https://github.com/demiroren-teknoloji/django-admin-autocomplete-list-filter): makes autocomplete list filters possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django custom list_filter by inheriting `django.contrib.admin.SimpleListFilter`

Here is a quick example:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MultiSelectFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    # Filter title
    title = 'Cities'

    # model field
    parameter_name = 'city_name'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        # you can modify this part, this is less DRY approach.
        # P.S. assuming city_name is lowercase CharField
        return (
            ('city1,city2,city3', 'City1 or City2 or City3'),
            ('city4,city5,city6', 'City3 or City4 or City6'),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):

        if self.value() in ('city1,city2,city3', 'city4,city5,city6'):
            # filter if a choice selected
            return queryset.filter(city_name__in=self.value().split(','))
        # default for no filtering
        return queryset
```

You have a reference to Docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to implement multiple select filters using [django-filter](https://pypi.org/project/django-filter/) package:

```
def form_filter_factory(filterset_class=None, model=None, fields=None, **kwargs):
   if not filterset_class:
       meta_fields = {'model': model}
       if fields:
           meta_fields['fields'] = fields
       opts = type('Meta', (object, ), meta_fields)
       set_fields = {'Meta': opts}
       set_fields.update(kwargs)
       filterset_class = type('{}AdminFilterSet'.format(model.__name__),
                              (django_filters.FilterSet,),
                              set_fields)
    return type('CustomFormListFilter', (FormListFilter,),
            {'filterset_class': filterset_class})


class PersonFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    city = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=City.objects.all(),
        label='Cities')

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('city',)

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = form_filter_factory(PersonFilterSet),
```

This solution is better because many Django projects are already using django-filter package, so no additional dependency is required just for the admin filters.

Comment: what's `form_filter_factory` here?

Comment: @jakubste Sorry, edited answer to include `form_filter_factory` source code.